# showing duplicate variable "page" in jsp code

Tags: jsp

```
  <%

  String page=request.getParameter("page");
  String sid=request.getParameter("id");
  int id=Integer.parseInt(sid);
  int i=BabyNameDao.update(obj,id);

  if(i>0){

      response.sendRedirect("viewbabynames.jsp?page="+page);
  }else{

      response.sendRedirect("viewbabynames.jsp?page="+page);
  }

  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`page` is an implicit object available in scriptlets, that refers to the current page. Choose another name that doesn't clash with implicit variables.

Or much better, **stop using scriptlets**. Scriptlets were fine to use in 2000. Since then, they've been continuously discouraged in favor of the JSP EL, the JSTL, and other taglibs.

And JSPs are a view technology. Updating the database and redirecting should be done in a controller, written in Java. Not in a JSP. Read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)